# How can I write a large csv file using Python?

Tags: python, csv

I need to extract a big amount of data(>1GB) from a database to a csv file. I'm using this script:

```
rs_cursor = rs_db.cursor()
rs_cursor.execute("""SELECT %(sql_fields)s
                     FROM table1""" % {"sql_fields": sql_fields})
sqlData = rs_cursor.fetchall()
rs_cursor.close()

c = csv.writer(open(filename, "wb"))
c.writerow(headers)
for row in sqlData:
    c.writerow(row)
```

The problem comes when is writing the file the system runs out of memory. In this case, is there any other and more efficient way to create a large csv file?

Comment: The problem most probably is with `sqlData`, not the fact the you write this data to a file. Where does this data come from? Do you have any control over it? if you do, you should be looking into reading it in chunks or as a generator.

Comment: How are you getting the SQL data?  Can you show us that code?

Comment: I added the bit of code of sqlData. The data is coming from a massive table.

Comment: What database/library are you using? In `pymssql` you can use `fetchmany` with the  `size` argument so it doesn't return the whole table at once, see its [docs](http://pymssql.org/en/latest/ref/pymssql.html?highlight=fetch#pymssql.Cursor.fetchmany) You can also consider using `WHERE` in order to `SELECT` from the table in chunks.

Comment: Thanks DeepSpace, I'm using psycopg2 (redshift). In that case, how can I write the file without overwriting it if I'm reading by chunks?

Comment: You can use the append-binary flag, `'ab'`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`psycopg2` (which OP uses) has a `fetchmany` method which accepts a `size` argument. Use it to read a certain number of lines from the database. You can expirement with the value of `n` to balance between run-time and memory usage.

`fetchmany` docs: http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/cursor.html#cursor.fetchmany

```
    rs_cursor = rs_db.cursor()
    rs_cursor.execute("""SELECT %(sql_fields)s
                         FROM table1""" % {"sql_fields": sql_fields})
    c = csv.writer(open(filename, "wb"))
    c.writerow(headers)

    n = 100
    sqlData = rs_cursor.fetchmany(n)

    while sqlData:
        for row in sqlData:
            c.writerow(row)
        sqlData = rs_cursor.fetchmany(n)

   rs_cursor.close()
```

You can also wrap this with a generator to simplify the code a little bit:

```
def get_n_rows_from_table(n):
    rs_cursor = rs_db.cursor()
    rs_cursor.execute("""SELECT %(sql_fields)s
                             FROM table1""" % {"sql_fields": sql_fields})
    sqlData = rs_cursor.fetchmany(n)

    while sqlData:
        yield sqlData
        sqlData = rs_cursor.fetchmany(n)
    rs_cursor.close()

c = csv.writer(open(filename, "wb"))
c.writerow(headers)

for row in get_n_rows_from_table(100):
    c.writerow(row)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried fetchone()?

```
rs_cursor = rs_db.cursor()
rs_cursor.execute("""SELECT %(sql_fields)s
                     FROM table1""" % {"sql_fields": sql_fields})

c = csv.writer(open(filename, "wb"))
c.writerow(headers)
row = rs_cursor.fetchone()
while row:
    c.writerow(row)
    row = rs_cursor.fetchone()

rs_cursor.close()
```

Comment: While this approach will work, it can be very slow as database I/O tends to be a slow process.

Comment: You can see my answer for another approach using `fetchmany`.